# "Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for minus operator" in SSRS query designer/refresh fields

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a valid query (tested in SSMS and also running fine in report Preview) however it will not update the dataset with the fields.

How can I force it to do so without manually entering all the fields?

Currently, if I click "Refresh Fields" I get the above error returned

Comment: Could you share this "valid query" with us, please?

Comment: The query runs in SSMS, it returns column headers if run with SET FMTONLY ON, it runs in BIDS in the preview panel. I'm interested to know why you think the issue is with the query? It even works if you start over with a new report, use the wizard and paste the query in to it. But I need to add it to an existing report

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is or not. But if you have a SQL syntax error being reported, it can often be helpful to look at the syntax of the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the report/dataset parameters were correctly defined, in order to get the fields returned, you have to hard code a bunch of

```
DECLARE @BILLGATES VARCHAR(100) = 'BEL-LEND'
```

statements at the top of the query, then remove them once you've refreshed the fields

(this is within the query windows in the dataset definition, also poor is the fact that once you click 'refresh fields' there is no visual indication of any means to indicate success/failure/anything)

Comment: Hmm. You don't happen to have capitalisation variances in your variables, do you? e.g. with `@BILLGATES` in one place, and `@BillGates` in another? If so, try changing them to use the same capitalisation throughout and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: No I saw that post. They were all lower case and it worked everywhere except the query designer, so I tried making them all upper case and it still didn't work.